# Как сделать в asp.net в .cshtml еще одну страницу?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть несколько страниц у которых будет один и тот же header, как вынеся его в отдельный файл загрузить на те страницы??

Comment: Использовать layout страницу

Comment: @tym32167, спаасибо. Вроде то

Comment: [Мастер-страницы](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/4.4.php)